# Find Test Executions containing Tests in a certain Test Set

Tags: jql, jira-xray

I'm trying to put together a JQL query within my Test Case Management project in X-Ray, but so far to no avail:

This is my scenario: 
I have a Test Set, `ABC-100`, with some Tests, `ABC-101` to `ABC-110`.

I also have some test executions, `ABC-120`, and `ABC-121`, with different selections of tests between the ones mentioned before.

I need a query that, given a Test Set identifier, returns the Test Executions 'related' in some way to that Test Set (e.g., containing some of the Tests that are inside of that Test Set).

So far, I have found:

- `key in TestSetTests("ABC-100")`, returns the *Tests* in the Test Set.
- `key in TestExecutionsTests("ABC-120")` returns the *Tests* in the Test Execution.
- `key in testTestExecutions("ABC-105")` returns the *Test Executions* that contain that Test.
- `key in testTestExecutions("ABC-100")` returns an error for ABC-100 is not a Test, but a Test Set. This would be the output I would be hoping for.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Having some equivalent to the TestSetPartiallyIn() for Test Execution would solve this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just to clarify that Test Executions (and Test Plans) contain only (references to) Tests.
TestSetPartiallyIn(<test_execs>) can return test sets that have some tests executed in the given test executions.
But what you want is slightly different from this: you need the test executions that have tests part of a given test set.
You have to perform this in two steps.

1. build a saved filter  (e.g. "my_tests_filter") to obtain the tests of a given test set.

```
issue in testSetTests(CALC-123)
```

2. use a JQL to obtain the test executions related, in part or fully, to those tests:

```
issue in testTestExecutions('my_tests_filter')
```

Comment: this is the closest to solve my problems, making use of a saved filter is a workaround for a lot of things! Thank you!